# Bootstrap 4 Botones en la parte inferior de Cards sin importar altura

Tags: bootstrap

tengo el siguiente código:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/230/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">

      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
         <a href="#" class="mx-auto btn-block btn btn-outline-info">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        <a href="#" class="mx-auto btn-block btn btn-outline-secondary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/230/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

en las dos primeras cards tengo botones, sin embargo quisiera que quedaran en la parte inferior al mismo nivel sin importar el tamaño de la Card, ¡puede hacerse con alguna clase de bootstrap? o hay que hacerlo  con un css adicional?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/230/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">

      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info col-xs-3">#1</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success col-xs-3">#2</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-danger col-xs-3">#3</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-default col-xs-3">#4</a>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Gracias, sin embargo me referia a que los botones se alinearan aunque estuvieran en diferentes cards no se si me hago entender

Comment: alineados con respecto a...? yo veo alineados los botones en la parte inferior de la tarjeta

Comment: si lo pones en una pantalla amplia no se ven alineados :/

Comment: bueno solo les estoy especificando cuantas col deben ocupar para tamaños extra-small (xs) coloca el tamaño que deben ocupar cuando sean sm, md, y lg para que cubra todas las resoluciones

Comment: el problema no es el tamaño que ocupan, mira mejor te subo una imagen.
https://ibb.co/npPGyQ

como ves los botones no se alinean, porque cada card tiene un contenido distinto aunque el tamaño si es el mismo

Comment: @AndressBlend el div que contiene los botones dale un position: absolute y un bottom: 15px. Edite mi respuesta crea una clase con esas propiedades y se la asignas a los div que contienen los botones. deberia funcioonar

Comment: pero el position absolute  hace que el boton se salga del cardview

Comment: como puedes ver en mi respuesta si lo pruebas, los botones no se salen de la tarjeta

Answer (score 1):

Para eso debes usar el footer de las cards como te muestro en el siguiente:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/230/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">

            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="#" class="mx-auto btn-block btn btn-outline-info f">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="#" class="mx-auto btn-block btn btn-outline-secondary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/230/180" alt="Card image cap" style="margin:0.4rem;">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Una salida fácil es usar un `<br>`, para que el texto quede a la misma altura.

No te compliques.

Comment: Hola Luis Larco, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por su longitud y contenido. Aunque la respuesta podría ser válida, sería bueno que indicaras dónde habría que poner ese `br` para que el texto de la pregunta quede a la misma altura. Lee [answer] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y ganar tu primera medalla). Un saludo.